# underscore.js .keys and .omit not working as expected

Tags: javascript, object, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm running a MongoDB with access via Mongoose to store user records.  I also have underscore on the server.  I have a RESTful API with a route that returns a collection (array of objects) from the database. I want to return the full collection to the client **but** remove the password element from each object so that doesn't get sent to the client.  Before anyone says anything, I will use bcrypt to salt and hash the password in the final version :)

Today I have just one entry in the database, for the user 'administrator'.  Here's the code in my route:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  User.find().sort({'userName': 'ascending'}).exec(function(err, data) {
    _.each(data, function (element, index, list) {
      console.log('userName=' + element.userName);
      console.log('password=' + element.password);
      delete element.password;
      console.log('keys: ' + _.keys(element));
      console.log('password=' + element.password);
      console.log(_.omit(element, 'password'));
    });
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

What I get sent back to the browser is:

```
[{"_id":"54058e6eb53dd60730295f59","modifiedOn":"2014-09-01T15:19:10.012Z",
"userName":"administrator","password":"stackoverflow","role":"administrator",
"__v":0,"createdBy":"54058e6eb53dd60730295f59","createdOn":"2014-09-01T15:19:10.004Z",
"previousLogins":[],"accountIsLocked":false,"loginAttempts":0}]
```

Which us fine, as the `res.json(data)` statement is just sending the raw `data` back to the browser - that's not the issue.  The issue is that the `delete` (and also if I use `.omit`) don't seem to work on my collection!  As you can see there are lots of `console.log` for debugging, here's what gets output:

```
userName=administrator
password=stackoverflow
keys: $__,isNew,errors,_maxListeners,_doc,_pres,_posts,save,_events
password=stackoverflow
{ _id: 54058e6eb53dd60730295f59,
  modifiedOn: Mon Sep 01 2014 19:19:10 GMT+0400 (GST),
  userName: 'administrator',
  password: 'stackoverflow',
  role: 'administrator',
  __v: 0,
  createdBy: 54058e6eb53dd60730295f59,
  createdOn: Mon Sep 01 2014 19:19:10 GMT+0400 (GST),
  previousLogins: [],
  accountIsLocked: false,
  loginAttempts: 0 }
```

The output of `_.keys` shows keys (I assume from an object prototype?) that I don't see when I `console.log(element)` but none of the keys that are accessible via `element.key`.

Any idea why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Comment: That's really weird. See, `_.keys` shouldn't access properties of object's prototype. What does `console.log(element.__proto__.constructor)` show?

Comment: Yes, seemed pretty weird to me too!  `onsole.log(element.__proto__.constructor)` outputs loads of entries... here's a pastebin link: [link](http://pastebin.com/vUkFabHY)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that `data` passed into `exec` callback function is actually a `Document` object - which can be thought of as a collection of `Models` created by Mongoose. These objects have plenty of useful methods, they remember connection with db etc. - but you won't be able to process them as plain objects.

The solution is to instruct Mongoose that you actually want plain JS objects as result of the query with `lean()`:

```
User.find().sort({'userName': 'ascending'}).lean().exec(function(err, data) {
  // process the data
});
```

Alternatively, you should be able to turn each model into a plain object with `.toObject()` method, then filter it:

```
var filtered = _.map(data, function(model) {
  return _.omit(model.toObject(), 'password');
});
res.json(filtered);
```

... but I'd rather use the first approach. )

Comment: raina77ow, that works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: If you can use ES6 then you can do it even easier. let normalObject = {...data['_doc']}